# 3D rotation - perspective

Tags: android, animation, 3d, rotation, perspective

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

LinearLayout rotator;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    rotator = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rotator);

    ObjectAnimator rotation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(rotator, "rotationY", 0, 360);
    rotation.setDuration(3000);
    rotation.start();

}
}
```

I've got above code, which is rotating View around Y axis. Problem is, that the perspective seems to be too "strong" - the edge of view that is in foreground becomes too big and the edge in background becomes too small. Is there any possibility to "lower down" the perspecitve factor?

Comment: Tags for Search Engines: In other words we adjust the ViewPoint along the z-axis by using setCameraDistance thus changing the depth of of the camera for the RotationX and RotationY flip animations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
int distance = 1900;
float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
rotator.setCameraDistance(distance * scale);
```

So this is the solution for all screen densities.