# Animation for rotation android

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

Is there any way to rotate image like Handel down and up in one animation 
like this [animation is here what i want like 3d view..](https://youtu.be/9bDs_afyr8A)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26512772/3d-rotation-perspective This may help you

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(yourImageView, "rotationX", 0.0f, 90f);
        animation.setDuration(1000);
        animation.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
        animation.setRepeatMode(ObjectAnimator.REVERSE);
        animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        animation.start();
```

Comment: but it is rotate full image i want bottom part of image fix

Comment: then split that image into two and rotate first part.

Comment: i did it but how to make two rotation i didnt get it

Comment: not two rotation. I said split image into two part and rotate only that part which you want to.

Comment: what you want? :)

Comment: image bottom part fix and just rotate like pull down handle i have screen like this https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-doKArYlxN2c/USkzbwFI_cI/AAAAAAAC1OQ/Rv_G8iJ3ffA/s1600/Brunopasso+PD+1-S+Plus+red.jpg and want only hanle rotation

Answer (score 3):

The answer is simple, you have to set the pivot of the view so that on rotating you can rotate view by axis. (In your case, this code will keep the view bottom same and animate the top of the view like you showed in the video)

[image]

According to the image if the levers bottom box is 25percentage of the image height, then you have to calculate the axis of the image to rotate for 25%.

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.animate_view);
    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            int percentageHeightOfBox = 25;
            int height = v.getMeasuredHeight();
            v.setPivotX(v.getMeasuredWidth() / 2);
            v.setPivotY(height - ((height * percentageHeightOfBox) / 100));
            ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0.0f, 90f);
            animator.setDuration(1000);
            animator.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
            animator.setRepeatMode(ObjectAnimator.REVERSE);
            animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
            animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    float rotate = Float.parseFloat(animation.getAnimatedValue().toString());
                    v.setRotationX(rotate);
                }
            });
            animator.start();
        }
    });
```

Comment: its working. i have tested this code. Image or view is  moving back. rest you can do with same code/idea.

Comment: @DharaPatel may be you haven't tried the code exactly, The code is working very well. Please try the exact code with pivot ad value animator.

Comment: i have tried but it not working like i need i have https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-doKArYlxN2c/USkzbwFI_cI/AAAAAAAC1OQ/Rv_G8iJ3ffA/s1600/Brunopasso+PD+1-S+Plus+red.jpg like this machine in main sceen i only need handle rotation

Comment: Now I get it, You want to spilt the image into two and rotate like the video you shared, am I right??

Comment: thank you it is working not exactly like video but it is working